# fluid not crossing a vertical effector boundary

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have the "H" shaped mesh (converted from Text object) Collider Effector that is allowing fluid to pass through the verticals, but as the mesh fills the fluid never crosses into the horizontal part midway up the "H".  I tried to add another inflow inside that area, and indeed nothing is flowing.  Yet from looking at the faces I see no solid or blockage in this section.

I'm about a month into fluid simulations and believe I understand many of the impediments (Surface Thickness >= 0.5, domain substeps and particle size appropriate, etc).

I include the blend file and pray that you geniuses can smack some sense into me ;-)  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "H" collision object needs to have normals orientated inside (red face orientation outside, blue inside) ... or your Domain is huge with very low Resolution Divisions ... or always good to Select all and Apply Scale ... or all of those :)

[image]

Comment: "Domain is huge":  Actually, it was a reduced, multiline, multi-word converted text mesh ("happy birthday someone's name" that I cut down to reduce your file size and simulation time.  "very low Resolution Divisions": I'll experiment with resolution, particle size now that the problem is solved.   Many thanks for your experience and time and keen eye.