# liquid collision effector result changes with minor location change

Tags: fluid-simulation

After a solution to yesterdays "[fluid not crossing a vertical Effector boundary](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214586/fluid-not-crossing-a-vertical-effector-boundary)" I now have yet another subtle Effector problem where a slight location change causes an effector to stop the fluid flow (no change in dimensions of Effector or inflow).

If I have the "EmitterCover.003" X location at 3' the flow is blocked.  If I move it to 3'2", there is no problem.  The flow is a child object that will move in accordance with the effector.

Let me know if you have any reasoning why this occurs, else I need to play with tweeking locations when this occurs as a workaround.

The blender file here is a reduction of the meshes and flows, is why the Domain is much larger.   [image]

[image]

blender 2.91.2

Comment: I can't confirm your issue, it works for any location on my side with your file.

Comment: Given the previous users comment, is it possible it has to do with an outdated cachet?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard: No, I "Free Data" from the Domain after each simulation.